# How to remove an <i> tag with a certain value from XML List through SQL Statement (Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio)

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xquery

I have a simple XML List, which looks like this:

```
<i>8</i>
<i>20</i>
<i>24</i>
```

For this example I want to remove the 2nd Node from this List.

How do I do that?

```
DECLARE @xml XML;

SET @xml = <i>8</i><i>20</i><i>24</i>

SELECT @xml.modify('delete <i>20</i>')
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removes nodes from the xml where text equals value of 20:

```
DECLARE @xml XML = '<i>8</i><i>20</i><i>24</i>';
SET @xml.modify('delete i[text()="20"]')
select @xml;
```

Removes the 2nd "i" node in the XML:

```
DECLARE @xml XML = '<i>8</i><i>20</i><i>24</i>';
SET @xml.modify('delete i[2]')
select @xml;
```

Bonus: Removes nodes from the xml where text contains a value of 20:

```
DECLARE @xml XML = '<i>8</i><i>20 </i><i>24</i>';
SET @xml.modify('delete i[text()][contains(.,"20")]')
select @xml;
```

Comment: Thank you guys! Both answers from SteveD and Shnugo work

Comment: Hi Steve, both your solution have some flaws: You should not check for `contains` but for equality. Your predicate `[text()][contains(.,"20")]` will first look if a `text()` exists and the check **the whole content** for any occurance of "20". This would touch even deeper nodes... And in both solutions you are using the *deep search* (`//i`) unnecesssarily. This can be dangerous, especially in deeper structures where a node's name might be repeated. `//i` will literally search for **any `<i>`element**...

Comment: @PhilippWeigel As you are new here (Btw: Welcome!) please allow me one hint: It is very kind of you to say Thank you, but it would be even kinder, to tick the acceptance check below the (best in your choice) answer's vote counter. This will 1) mark this issue as solved 2) make it easier for followers to find the best solution 3) pay points to the answerer and 4) pay points to you. Once you've crossed the 15 points border yourself, you are  - additionally - asked to vote on contributions. This is the SO-way to say thank you. Happy Coding!

Comment: @Shnugo: Thanks for the feedback.  Edited to reflect your comments.  Retained the "contains" example for reference purposes, should the text contain a space, etc, this can be useful.

Comment: @PhilippWeigel not quite... Your predicate should look like `delete i[text()="20"]` Furthermore your predicate is still not correct. Try your last example (the Bonus with `conatins`) with this XML `'<i>8</i><i>10<x>20</x></i><i>24</i>'`. Now try it again, but without the `10`. You see what I mean? You are purely checking, if a `text()` exists...

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this

```
DECLARE @xml XML;

SET @xml = N'<i>8</i><i>20</i><i>24</i>';

DECLARE @pos INT=2;
SET @xml.modify('delete /i[sql:variable("@pos")][1]');

SELECT @xml;
```